# Unity slider only works from one side in 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, slider, virtual-reality

I am trying to create a slider using Unity to be used in a 3d environment but the sliders only work from one side, it seems like they only work in a 2d plane.

I replaced the handler of the slider with a sphere to check if that would make the collider work as a 3d slider but it is only working from one side.

Comment: This seems to be the intended behaviour. All Unity.UI components basically only work from the front side (incuding buttons etc)

Comment: Is there a way to change that?